# Как просмотреть локальные файлы на Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, heroku

Кто может помочь, зделал своего бота для тг и залил его на Heroku через git, в бота я добавил базу данных в которую бот вносит адреса новых юзеров. Вопрос: мне надо посмотреть эту базу но я не пойму где она находится, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В Heroku нет возможности просмотреть файлы на сервере (по крайней мере, в бесплатном тарифе). Более того, если вы используете обычную базу данных, а не рекомендованную Amazon DB, то при обновлении сервера все её данные удалятся.

Если вам нужен простой хостинг для телеграм-бота на python, в котором можно просматривать файлы, то я рекомендую [сайт pythonanywhere.com](https://pythonanywhere.com).